# Playwright Parameterized Tests via Helper Function

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

Is there any way to create a playwright test that can run multiple times via a helper function. I've found that running a test inside of a for loop works fine for providing different data. However, I'd like to be able to create a helper function that wraps (or otherwise replaces) playwright's test function, so that I can populate it with data automatically. What I have functions fine when run via the command line but breaks some stuff with the vscode extension and UI Mode, meaning that tests can't be debugged properly.
My current approach:

```js
import { test as baseTest } from "@playwright/test";

const registerData = (config) => {
    const test = (title, testFunction) => {
        // Some code to generate permutations from config
        // filteredEntries is an array of field names and the type of data to populate them with

        const permutations = [...getAllPermutations(config)];
        let variation = 0;
        let testData = {};
        baseTest.beforeEach(async ({ }) => {
            const permutation = permutations[variation];
            for (let j = 0; j < filteredEntries.length; j++) {
                testData[filteredEntries[j].name] = permutation[j].value;
            }
            variation++;
        });
        baseTest.describe(title, () => {
            for (let i = 0; i < permutations.length; i++) {
                baseTest(`Variation ${i + 1}`, testFunction);
            }
        });
    };
}
Object.assign(test, baseTest); // So that test.only, test.fixme, etc all still work
return { test, data };
```

The issue here is that I'm returning a new function instead of modifying playwright's test function, so all of the 'go to file' functionality in vscode's playwright extension breaks, and it refuses to run or debug any individual tests as the file containing the registerData function isn't a test/spec file (nor do I wish to display it as one). Note that I've tried adding it as a test file and it still doesn't allow me to run them via the vscode testing tab - I'm pretty sure I need to modify or hook into Playwright's test function instead of just calling it, similar to the `beforeEach` or `afterEach` functions.

I have a fully typed version with typescript, but it's pretty monstrous and would require about 5x the code to give proper context. I don't think it meaningfully adds to what I'm asking, so I'm not including it, unless anyone thinks it may actually be pertinent.

Essentially, I'm hoping to call the `registerData` function and use the test function it returns instead of the default playwright one. This test function would then run the test multiple times, populating the data object with different values each time.

It would be used as follows:

```js
const { test, data } = registerData({
    postName: 'title',
    postContents: 'paragraph'
});

// Would automatically be run multiple times.
// Each time, data.postName and data.postContents would be different
test("Create Post", ({ page }) => {
    await page.getByRole("button", { name: "New Post" }).click();
    await page.getByPlaceholder("Title").fill(data.postName);
    await page.getByPlaceholder("Body").fill(data.postContents);
    await page.getByRole("button", { name: "Done" });
    await expect(page.getByText(data.postName)).toBeDefined();
    await expect(page.getByText(data.postContents)).toBeDefined();
});
```